# SQL Server Instances Registry Key

Tags: sql-server, registrykey

I made an application to bring the SQL server instances that exists on the local machine, and I font there is a value at the registry key: **"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server"**  the value **"InstalledInstances"** brings all the instances that are downloaded on the local machine, but the question here is that, does this key and this value works, or contains the instances for all SQL server versions, in other word is this key supports all versions of SQL servers(2008 ...etc.) ? I already tried it on SQL 2014 and 2012 and it already contained their instances, but is that applicable for versions below as well? (at least until SQL server 2008)

Thanks

Comment: There is no 2010 SQL version.

Comment: I have checked on machine with SQL 2008 R2 (10.50.4000) and the value is there and populated.

Comment: Thanks for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this question is [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d49fa07b-b497-4298-80b7-ba7e4691e6c8/sql-server-instances-register-key?forum=winforms), and says:

Yes, InstalledInstances under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\ contains all names of installed instances on this computer(not including localdb). This does applies to all SQL Server versions since 2008, and according to current information it also applies to SQL Server 2017(based on CTP 2.1).

Comment: A simple external link as an answer is not acceptable. You should at a minimum provide a synopsis of the information at the end point of the link so that this question and answer might have some value after the link is no longer good.

Comment: i would appreciate an answer instead of a lecture

Comment: Sorry if I hurt your feelings - that was not my intent.  Please see this in Help Center on answering questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer -  "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."